# jquery delay doesn't seem to keep subsequent command from executing

Tags: jquery, delay

I have the following jquery code:

```
$j('#' + messageId).fadeTo(1000, .3).delay(3000).css("top", 20);
```

My expectation is that the following would happen when this ran:

1. the messageId div fades over one second, down to `.3` opacity
2. Nothing happens for 3 seconds
3. The messageId div moves to 20 pixels from the top

Instead, there's no delay.   Only steps 1 and 3 above happen, in reverse order, or in other words:

1. The messageId `div` immediately moves
2. After moving, the message fades over one second

Note: what I really want to do for the final step is a `remove()` call, to get the element out of the DOM, but that also seemed to "fire" too soon, so I thought I'd try setting this css position.

Does the delay only delay subsequent effects, and not a subsequent css setting or a `remove()` call?  Must I use the javascript `setTimeout()` function to accomplish my goal?

Comment: Maybe this code on the jquery.delay() page (http://api.jquery.com/delay/) offers a hint at the solution:  $('.foo').slideUp(300).delay(300).queue(function() {
$(this).remove();
});

Answer (score 4):

Use queue for non standard effects.

```
$j('#' + messageId).fadeTo(1000, .3).delay(3000).queue(function(){ 
   $(this).css("top", 20);
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MhLnV/1/).

Answer (score 2):

I believe the `delay()` function only works on jQuery's animation queue. The css function isn't part of the animation queue. You should do a callback with a timeout. For example:

```
$j('#' + messageId).fadeTo(1000, .3, function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#' + messageId).css("top", 20);
    }, 3000);
}
```